# tableViewCell not loading when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I know this question is beating a dead horse, but i've searched through all the previous questions and haven't found a solution that could help. I am using Firebase for my backend and storage. When a user uploads a photo it goes into my Firebase storage and followed a tutorial in caching the photos to go easy on data. The way in which I access the cached data is through this:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

extension UIImageView {

func loadImageUsingCachWithUrlString(urlString: String) {

    self.image = nil
    if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) as UIImage?{
        self.image = cachedImage

        return
    }


    let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data,response,error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error as Any)
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!){
                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                    self.image = downloadedImage
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

I access this extension through the function "loadImageUsingCachWithUrlString"

Moving into my table view, I am loading the users name age bio etc in each cell, I have Firebase persistence on (in case that makes a difference), the way in which I am downloading the users information into the cell is through this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell
    let cells = tableView.visibleCells
    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    let profileImageUrlThird = user.profileImageUrl
    let tableViewHeight = tableView.bounds.size.height
    cell.nameLabel.text = user.name
    cell.bioLabel.text = user.aboutMe
    cell.reviewRating.text = user.averageRating
    cell.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCachWithUrlString(urlString: profileImageUrlThird!)
    let tempNumber = user.profileView
    let stringTemp = tempNumber?.stringValue
    cell.profileViewCount.text = stringTemp
    cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Avenir", size:22)
    tableView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
    tableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    print(tableView.frame.height,tableView.frame.width)
    //tableview height is 670 table view width is 414
    print(cell.frame.width,cell.frame.height)
    //cell width is 414 cell height is 330


    for cell in cells {
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: tableViewHeight)
    }
```

return cell
}

The information loads and everything is fine, but as soon as I drag the cells disappear. Any help would be appreciated, I have been stuck on this for almost a week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tableView.dequeueReusableCell()` might return a `nil` value. As a result, there are no such cell in reuse pool, then you need to generate one yourself.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifer = "cell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifer)
    if cell == nil {           // when no reusable cell 
      cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: identifer) 
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "row:\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So basically check if the cell is equal to nil?

Comment: right, you can refer to the code above and give it a try

Comment: I'm getting a warning that says "comparing non-optional value of type"tableView.UserCell" to nil always returns false" is that cause for concern, or just disregard it?

Comment: it is because you warp a optional value to a non-nil value with 'as!', it mean the value must be a non-nil value, otherwise it will crash. just change it to as? , it's the language design